# angular 4 as SPA (single-page app) or MPA (multi-page app)

Tags: angular

I couldn't find a clear answer on the web. I want to ask you, angular 4 is better used on single-page apps ? I am asking this question because in angular's official documentation it hasn't any reference about angular 4 and multi-page applications.

Comment: Angular is meant to be used to build SPAs.

Answer (score 6):

I think it depends on your web app architecture.

**SPA**

Would be better in case you have to create a new fresh project. Where you will combine module lazy load and all other stuff.

The setup and bundling will be much easier to setup and this is easy with by using angular documentation.

**MPA**

This will be more applicable to some legacy web apps.
What I mean by this is that each page can be migrated step by step in some refactoring process to separated angular module app.

At the end of refactoring all this can be combined in SPA.

The biggest problem is bundling and code splitting.

For example, you can be split like this

- vendor.js
- polyfills.js
- page_1_module.js
- page_2_module.js
- etc

The layout would load the vendor.js and polyfills.js which are common for all pages, and for each page would use one of the page_{nr}_module.js

**Conclusion:**

You will not find the right answer, the right one is defined in your project and specifications.

Nobody told us that angular must be SPA for your full web app this can be used only where is required.

Answer (score 2):

A single-page application (SPA) is an app that works inside a browser and does not require page reloading during use. 
Multiple-page applications (MPA) work in a “traditional” way. Every change eg. display the data or submit data back to server requests rendering a new page from the server in the browser. 
Angular is a powerful Javascript framework for building SPA. 
Hope I help!